# Push animation without shadows and blackouts

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have a simple **iOS** `NavigationController` based application. Two `UICollectionViews`, one after another. If element on **"first collection"** was clicked, the **"second collection"** will be opened.
Quite simple.

**Important note:**

**"Both `UICollectionViews` have transparent background. General background color for `navigationController` is used. *(Inherited class from `UINavigationController`)*"**

**The problem:**
If understood it right, push method of `NavigationController` works according to algorithm:

1. Pushing view is created.
2. **Transparent gray overlay** is created **over** pushing view.
3. NavigationController pushes the view with standard animation. *(Gray overlay still there)*
4. Gray overlay disappears.

*(If pushing view has transparent background, a **gray vertical line** is visible)*

**[Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Z6mMUccagxLUo3R3lHMHhxT0k/edit?usp=sharing)**

**Next step:**
I've tried to solve this problem by overriding push method. Here's what I've got:

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
                           animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.45;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction 
           functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
    transition.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    transition.delegate = self;
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
}
```

This way creates its own push animation, but there were another standard animations used, which I can't remove. **(Blackout on presenting and hiding views)**

**[Screenshots_1_and_2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Z6mMUccagxVFdVa2F0ZFZjbjA/edit?usp=sharing)**

**Question:**
**"How can I push ViewController, without fading, blackout, and other animation filters?"**

Solutions with theme names (on **stackoverflow.com**)

- iOS 7 `UINavigationController` Push animation shadow
- iOS 7 shows black background in custom animation for Navigation

Don't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't override the push method. iOS7 allows you to provide animation controllers for custom transitions. See [here](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html) for more details.

Comment: That's nice, but why not just set 'animated' to 'NO'?

Comment: I understood from the question that the OP wants an animation but not the shadows. Read the question.

Comment: The problem is, that I need standard push animation, but without this shadows, etc.

Comment: @OrenciucEvghenii If you really want to dig in and don't mind getting your hands dirty, you can still use the navigation controller as the animation controller so you get the same animation, and then modify its internal view hierarchy. When a view is to transition out, it is moved to a transition view, and this is where all the things you don't want are. Hide them, and you will get what you want the dirty way.

Comment: oh.. didn't catch that. ok

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with blurred transparent view controllers. A dimming view is put behind during the transition.

I have to admit I really like iOS native transitions (especially with larges titles), and I guess it is pretty time consuming to reproduce them with the same level of quality. I came across numerous tutorials explaining how to create custom transitions but the result looked quite weird (Snapchat has its own UIScrollView interactive transitions from pages to pages, and personally, I find user experience weird because 90% of my other apps have native Apple transitions)

Anyway, if someone has the same problem of pushing translucent view controllers, here is my implementation of `pushViewController`.

Please note this is still quite silly and may not work for future versions of iOS. Correct me if I miss a better way to "override" native iOS VC transitions.

```
override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)
{
    let visibleVc = self.visibleViewController
    
    super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
    if(animated)
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration:transitionCoordinator?.transitionDuration ?? 0.2, animations: {
            visibleVc?.view.alpha = 0
        })
    }
    
    // at least in iOS 13, pushing a viewController creates, the time of the transition,
    // a dimming view that disappear only after the old view controller is removed.
    // this causes the blur to jump a tiny bit in brightness at the end of the push animation
    // to remove that "jump", we find the dimming view after a while (it's not present at the beginning), and animate it to alpha 0, from half animation time
    // FIXME: this is only a silly trick : it would be appropriate to create our own VC transition later 
    // Works at least with iOS 13, to be tested with iOS < 13 and iOS 14

    let halfDuration = (transitionCoordinator?.transitionDuration ?? 0.2) / 2
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:.now() + halfDuration ) {
        if let uiNavigationTransitionView = self.view.subviews.first(where: {
            String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "UINavigationTransitionView"
        }),
        let wrapperView = uiNavigationTransitionView.subviews.first(where: {
            String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "UIViewControllerWrapperView"
        }),
        let grayOverlay = wrapperView.subviews.first(where: {
            String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "_UIParallaxDimmingView"
        })
        {
            UIView.animate(withDuration:halfDuration, animations: {
                grayOverlay.alpha = 0
            })
        }
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a long time and eventually came up with this rather hacky way of doing it, which seems to work perfectly.

```
class UINavigationControllerKillDim: UINavigationController {
            
        private weak var displayLink: CADisplayLink?
    
        override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
            displayLink?.invalidate()
            let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(linkTriggered))
            displayLink.add(to: .main, forMode: .default)
            self.displayLink = displayLink
            super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
        }
                
        override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
            displayLink?.invalidate()
        }
        
        @objc func linkTriggered(displaylink: CADisplayLink) {                
            let parallaxViews = self.view.allParallaxSubviews()
            
            parallaxViews.forEach({ parallaxView in
                parallaxView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            })
        }
        
        deinit{
            displayLink?.invalidate()
        }
        
    }
    
    private extension UIView {
            
        func allParallaxSubviews() -> [UIView]{
            var all = [UIView]()
            func getSubview(view: UIView) {
                if String(describing: type(of: view)) == "_UIParallaxDimmingView" {
                    all.append(view)
                }
                guard !view.subviews.isEmpty else { return }
                view.subviews.forEach{ getSubview(view: $0) }
            }
            getSubview(view: self)
            return all
        }
    }
```

It basically finds every UIParallaxDimmingView (there are 2) and sets the background color to clear on every frame.

I think swizzling setBackgroundColor on _UIParallaxDimmingView might be a better route but I couldn't figure out how to swizzle a method inside a private class.