# Grey color background on pushing transparent background UIViewController inside a Container View (Storyboard)

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I'm pushing a `UIViewController` (*A*) with `clearColor` as background in a `UINavigationController` (*N*).

*N* is placed inside a Container View. This view has a background that I want to show always.

[image: Container-UINavigation-Push]

Then, when Push is animated it shows a grey/transparent background in my VC (*A*) and when it finishes its animation, it shows correctly.

Is there any way to avoid this grey color?

I have 'done' it by putting a white view background in *A* and making it disappear in `viewDidAppear` but I think it can be done without that trick...

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    __weak TestsViewController *weakSelf = self;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
        TestsViewController *ownSelf = weakSelf;
        ownSelf.backgroundView.alpha = 0;
    }];
}
```

Comment: how did you solve the issue finally? I found the same problem persists even with custom animation.

Comment: Finally I created a solid background VC and in viewWillAppear make it transparent. It's not a very elegant solution but I didn't find anything better.

Comment: I see. What I did was I superclassed the ViewControllers of both the Views, and assigned a background image to the superclass itself, so each child view has the same background image. Thus the above problem does not arise. This works fine! The only issue here is increased memory usage. But the increase in memory usage is about 10MB in my tests for my app, which iPhones/iPads should be  easily able to handle!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your app's window's background colour to white:

```
// applicationDidFinishLaunching
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

The push animation often ends up using the background colour of the window behind the transparent areas, and the window background colour is clear by default, so it shows black through the transparent navigation bars and toolbars.

**EDIT**: Sorry, misunderstood what the issue was. When you push a view controller with a transparent background colour, the background you see behind the view controller is the shadow that is rendered behind your view controller (you can see the edge of it when in a non-transparent view controller).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23396777/push-animation-without-shadows-and-blackouts) has an answer to your issue. Basically, you have to implement a custom animation controller, to provide the transition animation yourself (as described [here](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html)). It would probably be easier to continue using your trick than implementing your own custom navigation transition.

Comment: Yes but I need It to be clear because I need my background image to be shown always and If I set It to white It covers It. (obvious xD )

Comment: @Bisca what background image? If the application's main window has a clear background, it is rendered as black. Or are you already changing the window colour/inserting an image into it?

Comment: I have tryed It and It doesn' work. Gray/transparent view is showed in muy new ViewController... Just above the container. My App Window is white but I have placed a VC in with a container with a navigator. Them, in my animation I want to see my first VC.

Comment: @Bisca sorry, I misunderstood your issue. I found a solution, but it seems more painful than the workaround you are already using.

Comment: @Bisca no problem; sorry for the initial misunderstanding, I assumed you were referring to the dark background behind the navigation bar and tab bar (this is the issue I have had myself many times). Please mark this answer as accepted if this solved your problem.